# How to prevent blogger from converting my c++ source code snippet in compose view?

Tags: blogger

Say I write the following at the "Compose" tab of a blog post:

```
a->x(100)
```

I publish the post.

If I view the post, it is what I want, basically the above code.

The problem is when I come to the post to edit it again, it is changed:

```
a-&gt;x(100)
```

This is frustrating.

I am not a HTML geek, any straightforward solution?

[**UPDATE**]
I guess there is no simple solution here for people like me not willing to mess around HTML. A workaround is, when I have a blog with code snippet, I just write it in google doc and reference it in the blog.

Comment: You can also use Gists. They can be embedded into the blog with code highlighting. Refer to this for more information - http://robertgreiner.com/2012/04/using-github-as-a-syntax-highlighter/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to wrap the code with `<pre>` `<code>` tages then put it where you want in HTML tap instead of compose tap

```
<pre>
    <code>
        a->x(100)
    </code>
</pre>
```

Comment: Yes, it works. The problem is, once you click that "Compose" tab, it gets messed up immediately and seems no way to get back.

Answer (score 0):

This happens because the XML parser that Blogger uses escapes certain characters (Refer to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1091945/what-characters-do-i-need-to-escape-in-xml-documents/1091953#1091953) for more information).A way to stop the content from getting escaped is by enclosing it within -

```
<![CDATA[ 
 ... Your code ...
]]>
```

But Blogger only honors this when the content is present in `script` or `noscript` tag. Therefore, something that will work -

```
<noscript>
  <![CDATA[
    a->x(100)
  ]]>
</noscript>
```

But the `noscript` tag isn't rendered by the browser, so you will have to use a bit of JavaScript to make it show up

```js
document.querySelector('noscript').insertAdjacentHTML('beforebegin','<pre><code>'+document.querySelector('noscript').textContent.replace("<![CDATA[","").replace("]]>","")+'</code></pre>');
```

```html
<noscript>
  <![CDATA[
    a->x(100)
  ]]>
</noscript>
```

The above javascript snippet will render the content present inside the `noscript` tag. If you have multiple `noscript` tags in a page, then it will to be adapted to loop over them.